# ¿Pulsar enter con un botón del ratón?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una función que realiza un barrido automático de ratón, es decir, que va cambiando el focus por una página con dos botones del ratón y el tercero para hacer de click, pero no me termina de funcionar muy bien el click en algún foco.

He pensado cambiar el click por el botón <kbd>enter</kbd> pero no sé cómo hacerlo, he visto que con jQuery con el código 13 se puede saber cuándo se pulsa pero no sé hacerlo para pulsarlo.

Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que tengo ahora mismo:

```
$(":focusable").eq(0).focus();
var currentFocus = $(":focusable").eq(0);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prueba1").mousedown(function(e) {
    //1: izquierda, 2: medio/ruleta, 3: derecho         
    if (e.which == 3) {
      //PlaySound3("http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-06.wav");
      //PlaySound3("https://www.soundjay.com/button/button-30.wav");
      PlaySound4();
      if (currentFocus != undefined) {
        currentFocus.focus();
        currentFocus.trigger('click');

        if (currentFocus.prop('tagName') == 'A') {
          window.location.href = currentFocus.attr('href');
        };
      }
      return false;
    }
    if (e.which == 2) {
      PlaySound3();
      var focusables = $(":focusable");
      var current = focusables.index(currentFocus);
      var previous = focusables.eq(current - 1).length ? focusables.eq(current - 1) : focusables.eq(0);
      currentFocus = previous;
      previous.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if (e.which == 1) {
      parar();
      PlaySound();
      //PlaySound3("http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav");
      var focusables = $(":focusable");
      var current = focusables.index(currentFocus);
      var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
      currentFocus = next;
      next.focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Espero este evento te sea de ayuda**

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('contextmenu', function() {
        $(document).trigger($.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
        $("#caja2").focus();
       console.log('enter');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="contextmenu"></input>
<br>
<input id="caja2"></input>
```

Comment: ¿cómo lo puedo hacer dentro de la función del ratón? Es decir cambiando la parte del click? if (e.which == 3) {
      
      if (currentFocus != undefined) {
        currentFocus.focus();
        currentFocus.trigger('click');

        if (currentFocus.prop('tagName') == 'A') {
          window.location.href = currentFocus.attr('href');
        };
      }
      return false;
    }

Comment: ¿Ivan, puedes agregar una descripción de tu respuesta? además, no es necesario colocar "he editado mi pregunta" :) Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

A lo mejor no me he explicado bien, quiero que por ejemplo al pulsar el botón derecho del ratón se pulse el enter. Creo que las respuestas son sólo para controlar si se pulsó la tecla enter físicamente.
Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: E modificado mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto a ver si te sirve...

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('contextmenu', function() {
        $(document).trigger($.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
       console.log('enter');
    });
});
```